# Prove, or disprove. If $ab$ in the center of a group $G$ then $ab=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I believe the statement is wrong so I have searched to find a counterexample.

***Attempt to attempt to disprove:***

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G)$ its center. If $ab$ in $Z(G)$ we cannot say that $a$ or $b$ in $Z(G)$.

For example: Consider the quaternion group $\{\pm 1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$, $Z(G)=\{\pm 1\}$.

$i^2=-1\in Z$ but $i\not \in Z$

any hint to prove this statement, or counterexample; will be appreciated.

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as the one in the question body. Which should be answered ?

Comment: If $ab$ is in the center then $(ba)b=b(ab)=(ab)b$. Multiplying by $b^{-1}$ from the right you get $ba=ab$. As you have shown, it doesn't follow in general that $a$ and $b$ are in the center.

Comment: In any group, $ba$ is a conjugate of $ab$. Any conjugate of an element of the centre of a group is that element itself.

Comment: Sorry about confusing, body is just a attempt to disprove, and thank you for the answers

Comment: For the general linear group, the center is a diagonal matrix whereby any ab = ba = diagonal matrix. Flipping zeroes over the diagonal doesn't change the matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question does not ask to show that $a$ and $b$ belong to the center. Two elements can commute without being in the center: think to $b=a^{-1}$ with $a$ not in the center for an easy example.

On the other hand, if $ab$ happens to belong to the center, then it's true that $ab=ba$.

For your proof, consider that $ba=b(ab)b^{-1}$; since $ab$ is assumed to be in the center, $b(ab)b^{-1}=(ab)bb^{-1}=ab$.